# use mysql get diagnostics at another procedure

Tags: mysql

I wanna build a public err log procedure. Mysql 5.7.2
I tried use get condition in that same procedure, works.
I remember this way worked before, maybe old mysql version, or I changed setting. right now, @errNo, @errMsg always NULL.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_err_log`()
BEGIN
    GET DIAGNOSTICS @cno = NUMBER;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION 1 @errNo = MYSQL_ERRNO, @errMsg = MESSAGE_TEXT;
SELECT @errNo, @errMsg;
END

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
    BEGIN 
        CALL sp_err_log();         
    END;

    select 1;
    select * from tbl_not_exist;
    select 2;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**< MySQL 5.7.2**

> [13.6.7.7 The MySQL Diagnostics Area :: 13.6.7.7.3 How the Diagnostics Area is Populated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/diagnostics-area.html#diagnostics-area-populating)
>
> ...
>
> SQL statements clear and set the diagnostics area as follows:
>
> - When the server starts executing a statement after parsing it, it clears the diagnostics area for nondiagnostic statements that use tables. ...
>
> ...

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mcooTBwD3r4QiqdQCyP1Co/0).

**>= MySQL 5.7.2**

> [13.6.7.7 The MySQL Diagnostics Area :: 13.6.7.7.3 How the Diagnostics Area is Populated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/diagnostics-area.html#diagnostics-area-populating)
>
> ...
>
> SQL statements clear and set the diagnostics area as follows:
>
> - When the server starts executing a statement after parsing it, it clears the diagnostics area for nondiagnostic statements. (Before MySQL 5.7.2, the server clears the diagnostics area for nondiagnostic statements that use tables.) ...
>
> ...

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/v8W3rxABNn8qTwxDapYoxu/0).

Possible alternative solution (>= MySQL 5.7.2):

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_err_log`(
  `_MYSQL_ERRNO` INT,
  `_MESSAGE_TEXT` TEXT
)
BEGIN
  SELECT
    `_MYSQL_ERRNO`,
    `_MESSAGE_TEXT`;
END//

CREATE PROCEDURE `sp_test`()
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
  BEGIN
    DECLARE
      `_NUMBER`,
      `_MYSQL_ERRNO` INT;
    DECLARE
      `_MESSAGE_TEXT` TEXT;
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS `_NUMBER` = NUMBER;
    GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS CONDITION `_NUMBER`
      `_MYSQL_ERRNO` = MYSQL_ERRNO,
      `_MESSAGE_TEXT` = MESSAGE_TEXT;
    CALL `sp_err_log`(
      `_MYSQL_ERRNO`,
      `_MESSAGE_TEXT`
    );
  END;
  SELECT 1;
  SELECT NULL
  FROM `tbl_not_exist`;
  SELECT 2;
END//

DELIMITER ;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gTqACLdVTNgFeqY7CJnyvY/0).

Comment: Thank you very much for the detail about different version. So I understand it is impossible to do that for >= 5.7.2

Comment: @wa56: Indeed, MySQL now follows the SQL standard, see [Changes in MySQL 5.7.2 (2013-09-21, Milestone 12) :: Diagnostics Notes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-2.html#mysqld-5-7-2-diagnostics).